# SQL Variables not working in Excel Query

Tags: sql, excel

Hi I have a query that can not be represented graphically in Excel External SQL Server Query, because the query is not simple I can not set Excel Variables. Instead I try to set variables in the SQL using declare/set however when doing this it fails when trying to import the data.

Is there a way to get around this? I need a level of flexibility for running the query and piping the data into Excel..

Okay so here is an example as requested.

```
declare @enddate as datetime
set @enddate = (select max(rpt_week) from [results].dbo.t_Data)
Select * from results.dbo.t_Data
where rpt_week = @enddate
```

This will not run in excel, obviously my query is more complex but the use of variables is essential and I am looking for a way to have this work.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to some code.  I don't really understand your issue, but perhaps setting the provider to native SQL - Provider=SQLNCLI.  That's allowed me to build more complex queries in Excel VBA.

Comment: "Show some code" is what the last comment should say.

Answer (score 7):

When using declare values in Excel, you need to SET NOCOUNT ON

your sample would be as follows:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @enddate as datetime
set @enddate = (select max(rpt_week) from [results].dbo.t_Data)
Select * from results.dbo.t_Data
where rpt_week = @enddate
```

Answer (score 4):

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21417922/22114) on this subject which has a correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25631073/22114):

Use **SET NOCCOUNT ON** in your query.

I encountered the same problem as the OP when I tried to run an SP from Excel, which was supposed to return data from an embedded `SELECT`. It was caused by a *... row(s) affected* message being returned from the server. Apparently, Excel can't deal with this message correctly, and the returned data is ignored. Once I used `SET NOCOUNT ON` in my SP, the data was displayed correctly in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you wish, but here are some notes:

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

cn.Open ServerCon ''Connection string

''Straight sql
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE adate = (SELECT Max(adate) FROM table_1)"
rs.Open sSQL, cn

''Not a good idea, see procedure parameter below for a better way
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE adate = '" _
     & Sheets("Sheet7").Range("B2") & "'"
rs.Open sSQL, cn

''Stored procedure
rs.Open "ExcelTest", cn

''Stored procedure with parameter
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "ExcelTest"
cmd.Parameters("@enddate") = Sheets("Sheet7").Range("B2")
Set rs = cmd.Execute

''Write to Excel
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet12").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

You can also use Query Tables.