# how to show the result of a long SQL query with so many variables in excel?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powerpivot

I've recently written a long SQL query with so many lines and variables to get the accurate average of response time of different people. So, my question is how I can show them in excel using PowerPivot?? Because when I copy the whole query and paste it in the PowerPivot SQL statement section it throws an error whereas it runs accurately in SQL.

```
DECLARE @Leave TABLE
(
  [TimeU] datetime, 
  [TimeM] datetime,
  [TimeH] datetime,  
  [TimeSG] datetime,  
  [TimeS] datetime,   
  [TimeHR] datetime,  
  [TimeHH] datetime
)
DECLARE @LeaveD TABLE
(
  SName nvarchar(50), 
  kind nvarchar(50),
   number int 
)
DECLARE @LeaveAvg TABLE
(
  [DayA] int, 
  [HourA] int,
  [MinuteA] int,
  [Title] nvarchar(60)
)
DEclare @LeaveExactAVG Table
(
totalMin nvarchar(8),
Title nvarchar(60)
)

INSERT INTO @Leave ([TimeU], [TimeM], [TimeH], [TimeSG], [TimeS], [TimeHR], [TimeHH]) 
 SELECT
      --nvarchar5,--nvarchar8,--nvarchar9,--nvarchar10,--nvarchar11,--nvarchar12,     
      tp_Created as [TimeU], 
      datetime3 as [TimeM] , 
      datetime4 as [TimeH] , 
      datetime8 as [TimeSG] , 
      datetime5 as [TimeS] , 
      datetime6 as [TimeHR] , 
      datetime7 as [TimeHH]
  FROM [ORG].[dbo].[AllUserData]
  where tp_ListId='BC168B2F-0E03-451A-8902-2379E8C5B483' and tp_DeleteTransactionId=0x 
  and tp_Created>'2019-09-22' --and tp_Created<'2019-07-23' --nvarchar14=N'انجام شد'

 INSERT INTO @LeaveD (SName, kind, number)  
 SELECT 
      N'Leave' as SNmae, N'manager' as Kind ,count(*) as number 
  FROM [ORG].[dbo].[AllUserData] as kind
  where tp_ListId='BC168B2F-0E03-451A-8902-2379E8C5B483' and nvarchar14=N'manager' 
  And tp_DeleteTransactionId=0x and tp_Created>'2019-09-22' --and tp_Created<'2019-07-23'
  union
  SELECT 
      N'Leave' as SNmae, N'officer' as Kind ,count(*) as number 
  FROM [ORG].[dbo].[AllUserData] as kind
  where tp_ListId='BC168B2F-0E03-451A-8902-2379E8C5B483' and nvarchar14=N'officer' 
  And tp_DeleteTransactionId=0x and tp_Created>'2019-09-22' --and tp_Created<'2019-07-23'
   union
  SELECT 
      N'Leave' as SNmae, N'security' as Kind ,count(*) as number 
  FROM [ORG].[dbo].[AllUserData] as kind
  where tp_ListId='BC168B2F-0E03-451A-8902-2379E8C5B483' and nvarchar14=N'security' 
  And tp_DeleteTransactionId=0x and tp_Created>'2019-09-22' --and tp_Created<'2019-07-23'
  union
  SELECT 
      N'Leave' as SNmae, N'especialist' as Kind ,count(*) as number 
  FROM [ORG].[dbo].[AllUserData] as kind
  where tp_ListId='BC168B2F-0E03-451A-8902-2379E8C5B483' and nvarchar14=N'especialist' 
  And tp_DeleteTransactionId=0x and tp_Created>'2019-09-22' --and tp_Created<'2019-07-23'
   union
  SELECT 
      N'Leave' as SNmae, N'HRB' as Kind ,count(*) as number 
  FROM [ORG].[dbo].[AllUserData] as kind
  where tp_ListId='BC168B2F-0E03-451A-8902-2379E8C5B483' and nvarchar14=N'HRB' 
  And tp_DeleteTransactionId=0x and tp_Created>'2019-09-22' --and tp_Created<'2019-07-23'
  union
  SELECT 
      N'Leave' as SNmae, N'HRM' as Kind ,count(*) as number 
  FROM [ORG].[dbo].[AllUserData] as kind
  where tp_ListId='BC168B2F-0E03-451A-8902-2379E8C5B483' and nvarchar14=N'HRM' 
  And tp_DeleteTransactionId=0x and tp_Created>'2019-09-22' --and tp_Created<'2019-07-23'
   union
  SELECT 
      N'Leave' as SNmae, N'finished' as Kind ,count(*) as number 
  FROM [ORG].[dbo].[AllUserData] as kind
  where tp_ListId='BC168B2F-0E03-451A-8902-2379E8C5B483' and nvarchar14=N'finished' 
  And tp_DeleteTransactionId=0x and tp_Created>'2019-09-22' --and tp_Created<'2019-07-23'
  and nvarchar8<>N'No' and nvarchar9<>N'No' and nvarchar10<>N'No' and nvarchar11<>N'No' and nvarchar12<>N'No' and nvarchar5<>N'No'
   union
  SELECT 
      N'Leave' as SNmae, N'رد شده' as Kind ,count(*) as number 
  FROM [ORG].[dbo].[AllUserData] as kind
  where tp_ListId='BC168B2F-0E03-451A-8902-2379E8C5B483' and nvarchar14=N'finished' 
  And tp_DeleteTransactionId=0x and tp_Created>'2019-09-22' --and tp_Created<'2019-07-23'
  and (nvarchar8=N'No' or nvarchar9=N'No' or nvarchar10=N'No' or nvarchar11=N'No' or nvarchar12=N'No' or nvarchar5=N'No')

INSERT INTO @LeaveAvg ([DayA],[HourA],[MinuteA],[Title])   
select      
        (DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeU]),max([TimeM]))/60)/24 as [DayA]      
        ,(((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeU]),max([TimeM]))/60)))-(((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeU]),max([TimeM]))/60)/24)*24) as [HourA]
        ,DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeU]),max([TimeM]))-((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeU]),max([TimeM]))/60)*60) as [MinuteA]
        ,N'M speed' as [Title]

from @Leave
where TimeM is not null
group by [TimeU] , [TimeM]

INSERT INTO @LeaveAvg ([DayA],[HourA],[MinuteA],[Title])   
select      
        (DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeM]),max([TimeH]))/60)/24 as [DayA]      
        ,(((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeM]),max([TimeH]))/60)))-(((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeM]),max([TimeH]))/60)/24)*24) as [HourA]
        ,DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeM]),max([TimeH]))-((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeM]),max([TimeH]))/60)*60) as [MinuteA]
        ,N'O speed' as [Title]

from @Leave
where TimeH is not null and TimeM is not null
group by [TimeM] , [TimeH]

INSERT INTO @LeaveAvg ([DayA],[HourA],[MinuteA],[Title])   
select      
        (DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeH]),max([TimeSG]))/60)/24 as [DayA]      
        ,(((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeH]),max([TimeSG]))/60)))-(((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeH]),max([TimeSG]))/60)/24)*24) as [HourA]
        ,DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeH]),max([TimeSG]))-((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeH]),max([TimeSG]))/60)*60) as [MinuteA]
        ,N'S speed' as [Title]      
from @Leave
where TimeSG is not null AND TimeH is not null
group by [TimeH] , [TimeSG]

INSERT INTO @LeaveAvg ([DayA],[HourA],[MinuteA],[Title])   
select      
        (DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeH]),max([TimeS]))/60)/24 as [DayA]      
        ,(((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeH]),max([TimeS]))/60)))-(((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeH]),max([TimeS]))/60)/24)*24) as [HourA]
        ,DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeH]),max([TimeS]))-((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeH]),max([TimeS]))/60)*60) as [MinuteA]
        ,N'E speed' as [Title]

from @Leave
where TimeS is not null AND TimeH is not null and TimeSG is null
group by [TimeH] , [TimeS]

INSERT INTO @LeaveAvg ([DayA],[HourA],[MinuteA],[Title])   
select      
        (DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeSG]),max([TimeS]))/60)/24 as [DayA]      
        ,(((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeSG]),max([TimeS]))/60)))-(((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeSG]),max([TimeS]))/60)/24)*24) as [HourA]
        ,DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeSG]),max([TimeS]))-((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeSG]),max([TimeS]))/60)*60) as [MinuteA]
        ,N'E speed' as [Title]

from @Leave
where TimeS is not null AND TimeSG is not null
group by [TimeSG] , [TimeS]

INSERT INTO @LeaveAvg ([DayA],[HourA],[MinuteA],[Title])   
select      
        (DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeS]),max([TimeHR]))/60)/24 as [DayA]      
        ,(((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeS]),max([TimeHR]))/60)))-(((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeS]),max([TimeHR]))/60)/24)*24) as [HourA]
        ,DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeS]),max([TimeHR]))-((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeS]),max([TimeHR]))/60)*60) as [MinuteA]
        ,N'HRB speed' as [Title]

from @Leave
where TimeS is not null and TimeHR is not null
group by [TimeU] , [TimeM]

INSERT INTO @LeaveAvg ([DayA],[HourA],[MinuteA],[Title])   
select      
        (DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeHR]),max([TimeHH]))/60)/24 as [DayA]      
        ,(((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeHR]),max([TimeHH]))/60)))-(((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeHR]),max([TimeHH]))/60)/24)*24) as [HourA]
        ,DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeHR]),max([TimeHH]))-((DATEDIFF(minute, min([TimeHR]),max([TimeHH]))/60)*60) as [MinuteA]
        ,N'HRM speed' as [Title]

from @Leave
where TimeHR is not null and TimeHH is not null
group by [TimeU] , [TimeM]

INSERT INTO @LeaveExactAVG(totalMin,Title)
select AVG(DayA*24*60+HourA*60+MinuteA) as totalMin
, Title
 from @LeaveAvg
 group by Title


select N'AVG' as TypeOfAVG,Title as ResponseType, CASE
    WHEN cast(totalMin as int) < 60 THEN cast(cast(totalMin as int) as varchar) +N' min '
    WHEN cast(totalMin as int) < 1440 THEN cast((cast(totalMin as int)/60) as varchar) +N' hour '+ cast((cast(totalMin as int)%60) as varchar) +N' min '
    ELSE cast(cast(totalMin as int)/1440 as varchar) +N' day '+cast(((cast(totalMin as int)%1440)/60) as varchar)+N' hour '+cast(((cast(totalMin as int)%1440)%60) as varchar)+N' min '
    END as ResponseTime 
from @LeaveExactAVG
`
```

Comment: When asking questions about why you get an error message it goes a LONG way to getting help by providing the error message.

Comment: One suggestion is put `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of your query. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43856724/why-does-set-nocount-on-fix-an-embedded-query-in-excel

Comment: Here is the error message: "OLE DB or ODBC error: Changed database context to 'ORG'.; 01000. An error occurred while processing table 'Query'.The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed."